# DataContext in not working when I implement MainWindow with some other class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datacontext

I'm new in WPF and I'm doing following code below as:

```
 public partial class MainView : ViewModelControl
    {
        public MainView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ViewModel1();
        }
}
```

As you can see I have my own class ViewModelControl. I have the following code below fro ViewModelControl class as:

```
 public partial class ViewModelControl : Window, IViewModelControl
    {
        public virtual void bindFirstDataContext()
        {
        }
        public virtual void bindSecondDataContext()
        {
        }
    }
```

I Modify the following XAML as:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.View.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainView" Height="262" Width="316">
```

Now the issue is that its show's error "**Partial declarations of 'WpfApplication1.View.MainView' must not specify different base classes**". It's not working as before as When I implement it with Window class as by default. Where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: MainWindow() constructor is not called. What is the behaviour of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Base class** for partial class declarations **should be same**. You have changed Window in code behind to ViewModelControl so that needs to be updated in XAML as well.

Change XAML declaration to this:

```
<local:ViewModelControl
        x:Class="WpfApplication1.View.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Namespace"> <-- HERE replace Namepsace with
                                                   actual namespace of class
                                                   ViewModelControl.

 ....
</local:ViewModelControl/>
```

Comment: Perfect answer. As I'm new in wpf, I perfectly understand that. :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your XAML:

```
<src:ViewModelControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Interface.MainView"  
 xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Interface" ...>

</src:ViewModelControl>
```

This will work, be carefull in the class attribute, write the fullname of your class ("namespace"."name of the class")

After "xmlns:src="clr-namespace:" you need to write the namespace where ViewModelControl is.

It need to be like that because MainView doesn't inherit directly from Window so you can't put a class name in the class attribute of a Window if it's not a direct child of window.

With this change it should work I tried it, if you still have some problem look again the namespace names it's easy to get confused.

Comment: Please check I do modify the question.

Comment: <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.View.MainWindow" > The class attribute is the fullName of your window class, so in this case it would be the class "MainWindow" in the "WpfApplication1.View" namespace, you don't have any class with this name, InitializeComponent will work only in this class